# How to scroll an inactive Tkinter ListBox?

Tags: python, events, listbox, scroll, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter GUI in Python. It has an Entry for searching with a results ListBox below it. The ListBox also has a Scrollbar. How can I get scrolling with the mouse and arrow keys to work in the ListBox without switching focus away from the search field? IE I want the user to be able to type a search, scroll around, and keep typing without having to tab back and forth between widgets. Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking I could just bind the mouse and arrow buttons to do the scrolling manually... http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet217059.html explains mouse scroll events, and arrow keys are easy. So now I just need to know what to bind them to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add bindings to the entry widget that call the listbox `yview` and/or `see` commands when the user presses up and down or uses the up/down scrollwheel.

For example, you can do something like this for the arrow keys:

```
class App(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry()
        self.listbox = Tkinter.Listbox()
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.listbox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        for i in range(100):
            self.listbox.insert("end", "item %s" % i)

        self.entry.bind("<Down>", self.OnEntryDown)
        self.entry.bind("<Up>", self.OnEntryUp)

    def OnEntryDown(self, event):
        self.listbox.yview_scroll(1,"units")

    def OnEntryUp(self, event):
        self.listbox.yview_scroll(-1,"units")
```

Comment: That makes sense. But how do I control them explicitly? So far I've just used mylistbox.config(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set) and myscrollbar.config(command=mylistbox.yview).

Comment: @Jeff: I've added some example code to my answer to address your question.

Comment: thanks! various websites made it sound complex, but with your example it's super easy.

Comment: One typo. `self.entry.bind("<Up>", self.OnEntryDown)` should use `self.OnEntryUP` instead.

Comment: After you have changed it to `self.OnEntryUp`,  `def OnEntryUP(self, event)` should also be amended to be the same.