# How to scroll list box item upward and downward using buttons in python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

here is my code i want to scroll the items inside my list box up and down using two button on right side of the tkinter window i have tried some method they did selected the items upward and downwar but the list box didn't get scrolled down
(open image below for better understanding)

```
 from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('450x400')
root.config(bg='#083D77')


# making a frame on left of the window
fr = Frame(root)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=4)

# LIST BOX INSIDE FRAME
lb = Listbox(fr, font=("Rockwell", 15, 'bold'), height=10, bg='#F4D35E', width=34, fg='#083D77')
lb.pack(side=LEFT, fill='both', expand='true')

for i in range(50):                  # item inside listbox
    lb.insert(i, 'This is sample data {}'.format(i+1))

# SCROLL BAR INSIDE FRAME
sbr = Scrollbar(fr, orient='vertical')
sbr.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

# linking scrollbar and listbox toghter
sbr.config(command=lb.yview)
lb.config(yscrollcommand=sbr.set)

# UP ARROW DOWN ARROW BUTTON
up_arrow = Button(root, text="▲", fg='#F95738',)    # up arrow
up_arrow.grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, sticky='s')

down_arrow = Button(root, text="▼", fg='#F95738')
down_arrow.grid(column=4, row=2, padx=5, sticky='n')


# select button

b1 = Button(root, font=("Rockwell", 15, 'bold'), text='SELECT', fg='red', border=2, relief='solid')
b1.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

[Click here to see the image of tkinter gui window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g7gW.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `<tkinter.Listbox>.see(index)`? For more info read [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111194626/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.see-method)

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from another question on stackflow

LINK ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559673/how-to-scroll-an-inactive-tkinter-listbox"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559673/how-to-scroll-an-inactive-tkinter-listbox)

now my code look like this to make this work

```
    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('450x400')
root.config(bg='#083D77')


def OnEntryDown():
    lb.yview_scroll(1, "units")


def OnEntryUp():
    lb.yview_scroll(-1, "units")


# making a frame on left of the window
fr = Frame(root)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=4)

# LIST BOX INSIDE FRAME
lb = Listbox(fr, font=("Rockwell", 15, 'bold'), height=10, bg='#F4D35E', width=34, fg='#083D77')
lb.pack(side=LEFT, fill='both', expand='true')

for i in range(50):                  # item inside listbox
    lb.insert(i, 'This is sample data {}'.format(i+1))

# SCROLL BAR INSIDE FRAME
sbr = Scrollbar(fr, orient='vertical')
sbr.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

# method for linking scrollbar and listbox
sbr.config(command=lb.yview)
lb.config(yscrollcommand=sbr.set)

# UP ARROW DOWN ARROW BUTTON
up_arrow = Button(root, text="▲", fg='#F95738',command=OnEntryUp)    # up arrow
up_arrow.grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, sticky='s')

down_arrow = Button(root, text="▼", fg='#F95738',command=OnEntryDown)
down_arrow.grid(column=4, row=2, padx=5, sticky='n')

    

b1 = Button(root, font=("Rockwell", 15, 'bold'), text='SELECT', fg='red', border=2, relief='solid')
b1.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

focus on those two new function **def OnEntryDown():**  & **def OnEntryUp():**

lambda function can also be use

```
up_arrow = Button(root, text="▲", fg='#F95738',command=lambda: lb.yview_scroll(-1, "units"))    # up arrow
up_arrow.grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, sticky='s')

down_arrow = Button(root, text="▼", fg='#F95738',command=lambda: lb.yview_scroll(1, "units"))
down_arrow.grid(column=4, row=2, padx=5, sticky='n')
```

Comment: You don't need the `global lb`. It's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @TheLizzard yes you are right i edited the code and then later i used lambda function.